# Draw point on image view with relative coordinates android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, touch-event

I'm working on the some geography quiz game.

User have to find some defined on the map.

I've made map point generator that calculates X and Y position relative to size of the image.
So X and Y of the place on the map are represented as: 
float * imageWidth = X 
float * imageHeight = Y;

Now when user touch image view, I have to draw on the map where correct position was.

When image view's scale type is defined as "FitXY" my code calculate position with those relative coordinates and the size of image's bounds, and that works fine, but map is stretched and doesn't look good.

When I use "centerInside" scale type...map image looks fine but my coordinates of the right position aren't point to the right place.

How to convert those coordinates to be corresponding with the real image drawn on the screen?

Also I need touch coordinates of the Bitmap not of the image view...so I can calculate distance between correct place, and touched place.

How to get canvas of bitmap drawn on the screen inside ImageView?

This is a little confusing for me...

Any idea?

Tnx?

EDIT:

This is my code so far:

Drawable drawable = stageImage.getDrawable();
                    Rect imageBounds = drawable.getBounds();

```
                // height and width of the visible (scaled) image
                int scaledHeight = imageBounds.height();
                int scaledWidth = imageBounds.width();

                Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
                stageImage.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);

                // map touch point from ImageView to image
                float[] touchPoint = new float[] { event.getX(),
                        event.getY() };
                inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);

                // Relative touch points
                float relativeX = touchPoint[0] / scaledWidth;
                float relativeY = touchPoint[1] / scaledHeight;

                // Prevent errors
                if (relativeX < 0) {
                    relativeX = 0;
                }

                if (relativeX > 1) {
                    relativeX = 1;
                }

                if (relativeY < 0) {
                    relativeY = 0;
                }

                if (relativeY > 1) {
                    relativeY = 1;
                }


                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();

     //THIS WORKS FINE!!!!!
                // Draw touched point
                stageImage.drawTouchedSpot(touchX, touchY);

                // Get correct relative position and draw it
                double correctRelativeX = gameHandler
                        .getCurrentMapElement().getxCoordinate()
                        * imageBounds.width();
                double correctRelativeY = gameHandler
                        .getCurrentMapElement().getyCoordinate()
                        * imageBounds.height();

    //THIS IS NOT RIGHT WHEN STAGE IMAGE SCALE TYPE IS "CENTER INSIDE"
                stageImage.drawFlag(correctRelativeX, correctRelativeY);
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to use ImageView.getImageMatrix()

Comment: It does I guess...but in reverse direction...I have for example that one city is at 0.5*width and 0.3*height of the original image...now I want to draw some flag animation on that position...but it's not correct when scale type of the image is "centerInside"...it is fine when it is "FitXY" but then map looks ugly and bad.

Comment: so i would suggest to create test image with some squares and click on its edges to test the code, make sure to place it in drawable-nodpi folder

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found answer for all my problems...

My code works great will little magic described here:

http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/

I've set image scaling type to "centerInside" but with scaleImage() method I can resize image view to fit my bitmap image...

That way relative coordinates are correct and I can draw animation on the place defined as correct one! Tnx anyway!

If you have better idea...I'm glad to try it...I guess this is not the most optimized aproach

Answer (score 0):

This mapping right here should already take the scaled width/height into account

```
float[] touchPoint = new float[] { event.getX(), event.getY() };
inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
```

So I don't believe you need this:

```
            // Relative touch points
            float relativeX = touchPoint[0] / scaledWidth;
            float relativeY = touchPoint[1] / scaledHeight;
```

Also, try changing your scale type to SCALE_TYPE.MATRIX and use the imageView's `getImageMatrix()` to modify the view.